# ¿Cómo hacer que un input tenga el focus al abrir un modal en react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, focus

Estoy trabajando con `React` para hacer un modal en el que se registren los datos de una orden de compra.

Lo que quiero lograr es que al abrir el modal el `focus` se ponga en un `input`, sin embargo, esto no sucede.

Ya probé usando `auto focus`, ya probé `use ref`, ya probé usando `document.getElementById('')` pero ningún método me funciona.

En otro post leí que esto sucedía por que el modal se renderiza al entrar a la pagina y cuando doy clic en otros botones el foco se sale del modal y por eso al abrirlo, el `input` ya no tiene el foco, pero no estoy seguro de que eso sea lo que sucede en mi caso.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

```
<CModal>
   <input autoFocus tyoe="text" />
<CModal/>
```

Comment: Está de más solicitarte que nos muestres tu código. [En esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) te explican por qué debes hacerlo.

Comment: Gracias,ya he actualizado la pregunta

Comment: Por favor agrega todo tu código (del modal y de javascript o react) con la que ejecutas el modal, para ver posible solución.

Comment: Este pequeño modal presenta elmismoproblema que tiene todo mi codigo, al abrilo pierde el foco, incluso si lo dejo con la propiedad de visible en true siempre pierde el focus el input

Answer (score 0):

Si tratas de realizar algo así

```
{ showModal ? (
   <CModal>
      <input autoFocus type="text" />
   <CModal/>
): null}
```

Comment: Hola, he intentado poner el modal de esta forma pero tampoco funciona como deseo

Answer (score 0):

Tenia el mismo problema y en mi caso se ha solucionado de la siguiente manera (hay que decir que lo he probado en typeScript, pero te lo he traducido a React).

Html:

```
    <CModal id="myModal">
          <input id="myInput" type="text"/>
   </CModal>
```

En el código:

```
const el3 = document.getElementById("myModal");
el3.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
  console.log("Se ha abierto el modal");
  const el4 = document.getElementById("myInput");
  el4.focus();
})
```

Puede ser que no lo haya acabado de traducir bien al react, pero te deberia funcionar

Comment: Es mejor no responder si no estás seguro de la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo de cómo focusear un elemento al montarse el componente. Lo referencias con `useRef`, y con un `useEffect` le aplicas el focus una vez que se monta el componente

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {
    const input = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        input.current.focus();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <form>
                <input type="text" ref={input} placeholder='Este input tendrá focus' />
                <input type="text" placeholder='Este input NO tendrá' />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
export default App;
```